# 特定フォーマットのデータから正規表現で目的の値を取得したい

Tags: python, 正規表現

以下フォーマットのテキストファイルから設定項目と設定をバラバラに取得するプログラムを作成中です。

<フォーマット>

```
test login_id: userid 
authority: root     folder: root123
login password: 1234***
```

<フォーマットの決まり>
・設定項目と設定の間は:と半角スペースがある。
例　
設定項目
folder:
設定root123

・設定項目は１つの言葉か複数の言葉で記載。設定内容は１つの言葉、スペースもない。
例　
設定項目（login password:）、設定（1234****)

・設定項目と設定のセットは１行に複数のセットがある場合がある。ただし、各セットのスペース数については決まりがない（１スペースだったり２スペースだったり）
例
authority: root     folder: root123

#### 実現したいこと

Pythonで辞書型としてそれぞれの値を取得したい。

```
data = [{"test login_id": userid}, {"authority": "root"}, {"folder":"root123"},{"login password":"1234***"}]
```

まだ、コードを書いていない状況での質問で恐縮ですが、私の実力では今現時点で何も思い浮かばず、先に質問させていただきました。
もし何かアイデアございましたら、ご教示いただけると大変たすかります。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 作りたいものに対して、**何がわからないか** を明確にしてください。プログラムを書くには細かい手順に分割する必要があり、今回の場合なら「ファイルを読み込む」「設定項目と値をバラバラにする (分割する)」「辞書型に代入する」などです。

Comment: 「実現したいこと」の辞書型は, 扱いにくそうに見えます。`data[1]['authority']` で `"root"` を取得でき `data[2]['authority']`ではムリなど。`data`を扱う予定の (利用する側の)コード(サンプルコード)もあるとよいでしょう。(質問者さんが扱えないようなデータが生成されても誰得なので)

Comment: 暖かいコメント、助言いただき本当にありがとうございます。まだまだ実力不足ですがご助言いただいた内容承知しました。

Comment: `r'\s*(.+?)[:?]\s+([^\s]+)` でよいかと。

Comment: metropolis様
ご助言ありがとうございます！確かにご指摘の通りです。
修正させて頂きます。

Answer (score 1):

**format_data.txt**

```
test login_id: userid
authority: root folder: root123
login password: 1234***
```

**Python script**

```py
import re

with open('format_data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = [{k: v} for k, v in re.findall(r'\s*(.+?):\s+([^\s]+)', f.read())]

print(data)

# [{'test login_id': 'userid'}, {'authority': 'root'}, {'folder': 'root123'}, {'login password': '1234***'}]
```

Comment: 社内環境で確認しました！問題なさそうです。ただ、:以外にも？という設定もあったので、そちらは教えていただいたコードをもとに対応したいと思います。本当にありがとうございました

Answer (score 0):

最終的に以下のような形になりました。色々とありがとうございました。

```
with open("system.txt") as f:
new_date = re.sub(':\s{2}', ': null', new_date1)

data = [{k: v} for k, v in re.findall(r'\s*(.+?)[:?]\s+([^\s]+)', new_date)]

print(data)
```

sytem.txt

```
test login_id: userid
authority: root folder: root123
login password: 1234***
make directory? yes source code:
```